# Missing Template for signout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Finally after about two hours of messing with this thing, I have figured out most of my 7 errors. That said, I have a new one, and I have no clue how to get rid of it. I seem to be having the same issue I did with a similar question I asked, and that was before I started over with my most recent git commit. Needless to say, I am not amused right now. Anyway, here's the failure:

```
1) Authentication signin with valid information followed by signout 
 Failure/Error: before { click_link "Sign out" }
 ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template sessions/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
     * "/Users/Brawain/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:45:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I actually don't know what code is necessary, so I'll post all my sessions stuff and the spec that's giving me trouble.

authentication spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

subject { page }

describe "signin page" do
before { visit signin_path }

it { should have_content('Sign in') }
it { should have_title('Sign in') }
end

describe "signin" do
before { visit signin_path }

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Sign in" }

  it { should have_title('Sign in') }
  it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }

  describe "after visiting another page" do
    before { click_link "Home" }
    it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
  end
end

describe "with valid information" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }   

    before do
        visit '/signin'
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
    end

    it { should have_title(user.first) }
    it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

    describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
    end
end
end
end
```

sessions helper

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
remember_token = User.new_remember_token
cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
!current_user.nil?
end

def current_user=(user)
@current_user = user
end

def current_user
remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
@current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end

def destroy
sign_out
redirect_to root_url
end

def sign_out
current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,
                              User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token))
cookies.delete(:remember_token)
self.current_user = nil
end
end
```

sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  sign_in user
  redirect_to user
else
  flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
  render 'new'
end
end

def destroy
end
end
```

sessions/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

<p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
</div>
</div>
```

This isn't the whole page, but this is my body html code. I've included it because it has the pertinent links.

```
<div id="announcements">
    TESTER TIME!    
        <% if signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the sessions_controller#destroy method is empty - that'll cause it to try to render the destroy view.  You probably mean to call the helper and redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to destroy session in destroy function and then if you don't want to dislay any logout screen then redirect_to root_path

Mostly people redirect after logout

Answer (score 0):

You must implement **destroy** method in **SessionsController**, not in **SessionsHelper**. Just move this method ( **"destroy"**) from **SessionsHelper** to **SessionsController**. It should be like this:

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 ...
  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper
  ...

  def sign_out
    current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,
                                  User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token))
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
  end
```